# Where to check out SLF4J Simple?

Tags: java, version-control, slf4j

I'm trying to check out `slf4j-simple-1.6.2` from a trusted repository (preferably, SLF4J's *official* repo) and pull it down into an Eclipse project. I'm doing this because I need to tweak SLF4J Simple's code so that it binds to my own logging implementation.

I'm hoping there is a way to do this without *having* to use Maven, because I've never used Maven before and feel much more comfortable running Ant builds.

Nevertheless, I've searched SLF4J's site high and low and cannot find any trusted links to their repository.

Even once I get the project imported into Eclipse, I still need to figure out how to get it building with Ant.

Could someone please help me:

- Find the repo
- Confirm whether an Ant build is possible

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simplest is just to download the latest source zip and work with that.

Answer (score 2):

The zip download [here](http://slf4j.org/download.html) also contains the sources.

Answer (score 2):

The official source code repository is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/ceki/slf4j). However, I believe you are doing it the wrong way.

The idea of SLF4J is to have a dependency on `slf4j-api` and let the developer to add exactly one binding. Instead of tweaking original bindings just write your own one. Of course you can use `simple` binding a starting point, but modifying existing open source libraries and maintaining patched versions is a lot of work.

Comment: I appreciate your response Tomasz but doing it this way is the actual recommended method from SLF4J's site. I guess there is just a whole lot of nasty config stuff if you start with a clean slate and attempt to implement your own binding. They make mention in several places to just start with slf4j-simple or slf4j-log4j and tweak the code to suit your needs. Thanks for the repo link though!  Also, any idea about Ant vs. Maven builds?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, slf4j is [present in the official Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Cslf4j-simple%7C1.6.4%7Cjar).

So basically, you have 2 simple solutions without using Maven:

1. Download the JAR / sources / javadocs from this Maven repository, and copy them in your own project directory.
2. Use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). This is an extension of Ant to give a better dependencies management. It can connect to Maven repositories. So you will be able to retrieve your slf4j dependency without having to use Maven.

Comment: +1 for Ivy. And also for linking the official Maven repo, since this seems to be a big deal to the OP.

Comment: Thanks romaintaz - if the official source code repo is at GitHub then do I need to install a git plugin for Eclipse so I can import it as a project? Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon You don't need to install a Git plugin just to checkout the sources from github. You have a "ZIP" button on top of the project page, which will let you retrieve everything you want. But if you just need to sources, why don't you retrieve the JAR that contains them from the Maven repository, as stated in my answer (you don't need to use Maven for that).

Comment: Well I am trying to import slf4j-simple into an Eclipse project so I can change the code and repackage it into a different JAR. This is the method SLF4J recommends using to build your own binding implementation. I already know what code I need to change in order to get my own binding to work, I just need to figure out how to get slf4j-simple into an Eclipse project. So far you guys have been great at getting me to the link where I can download the source from, but I am still not able to get the source imported into Eclipse...